# Update Records Apex

Tags: apex

Started learning APEX and I have hit a blocker. Im trying to do a very simple dml update but its not working, below is my code, any advice would be gretly appreciated:

My Trigger:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert) {


 if(AccountUtility.triggersAreEnabled()){
      AccountTriggerHandler handler = new AccountTriggerHandler(Trigger.operationType, Trigger.new, Trigger.old, Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);
      handler.execute();
  }
}
```

My Trigger Handler:

```
public with sharing class AccountTriggerHandler {
  private System.TriggerOperation triggerOperation;
  private List<Account> newList;
  private List<Account> oldList;
  private Map<Id, Account> newMap;
  private Map<Id, Account> oldMap;
  
  public AccountTriggerHandler(System.TriggerOperation triggerOperation, List<Account> newList, List<Account> oldList, Map<Id, Account> newMap, Map<Id, Account> oldMap) {
      this.triggerOperation = triggerOperation;
      this.newList = newList;
      this.newMap = newMap;
      this.oldMap = oldMap;
      this.oldList = oldList;
  }
  
  public void execute() {
    switch on this.triggerOperation {
        when BEFORE_INSERT {
          AccountUtility.consultancyUpsell(newList);
        }
        when AFTER_INSERT {}
        when BEFORE_UPDATE{}
        when AFTER_UPDATE {}
        when AFTER_DELETE{}
    }
  }

}
```

My Utility Class:

```
public with sharing class AccountUtility {

  public static void consultancyUpsell(List<Account> Account){
        List<Account> myAccount = new List<Account>();
        for (Account ac : myAccount){
            if (ac.Industry == 'Consulting') {
                Account a = new Account();
                a.id= ac.id;
                a.UpsellOpportunity__c='Maybe';
                myAccount.add(a);
            }
        }
        if (myAccount.size()>0){
            database.update (myAccount,false);
        }
    }


    public static boolean triggersAreEnabled()
    {
        if(Test.isrunningTest())
        {
            return true; 
        }
        else
        {
            return Global_Settings__c.getInstance().Fire_Triggers__c;
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks

Tony

Answer (score 3):

I want to start by commending you, as a new Apex engineer, for following some important best practices like using a trigger handling framework and practicing separation of concerns. You're on the right track, despite a couple of issues here.

This code:

```
        List<Account> myAccount = new List<Account>();
        for (Account ac : myAccount){
            if (ac.Industry == 'Consulting') {
                Account a = new Account();
                a.id= ac.id;
                a.UpsellOpportunity__c='Maybe';
                myAccount.add(a);
            }
        }
        if (myAccount.size()>0){
            database.update (myAccount,false);
        }
```

would be *mostly* correct if you were using an `after insert` trigger. In `after insert` context, records have Ids, as they've already been inserted into the database. You can then perform further DML on them (`update`) if necessary.

But `after insert` is the wrong pattern here, and would cause trigger recursion. Luckily, your trigger's already running `before insert`. In that context, records do not have `Id`s set yet, and you can mutate them *without performing DML*. Hence, you can reduce your code to

```
        for (Account ac : newAccounts){
            if (ac.Industry == 'Consulting') {
                ac.UpsellOpportunity__c = 'Maybe';
            }
        }
```

Note also that I've changed your list variable here. You were trying to iterate over `myAccount`, which is empty - it's the list you're trying to populate. That results in the code actually doing nothing at all, rather than trying and failing a bunch of DML operations.

You'll want to change the parameter name not to be `Account`, as that will have confusing results.

---

A few other notes:

You're using `Database.update()` with `allOrNone` set to `false`. This means that any DML failures won't raise an exception and roll the transaction back, and you could be left with inconsistent data. You're also not doing any work to try to handle the results, whether successful or failed. That *might* be what you want in this case, but it's often not.

Performing DML on an empty collection is a no-op, so you don't need to do

```
        if (myAccount.size()>0){
```

You may want to change your `AccountUtility` class to use instance methods rather than static methods to improve your ability to mock code in test contexts. I would also not call this a `Utility` class, myself. It's more like a [`Service`](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_sl).

Comment: As an added note, specifying `allOrNone = false` in a DML transaction will not cause static variables to be reset/un-set upon a partial failure. This can lead to some very confusing runtime behavior if you're not expecting it (and know _exactly_ what's going on). For 99% of users, I'd say it's just better to not use that.

Comment: HI David. Thank youi so much for taking the time to review. I have made some amendments based on you recommendations.

And it deploys okay from VS code and there are no errors upon unit testing ( which is a greate start) however,  nothign happends to my test records upon save.

If its not to much trouble would mind advising on how I can get the DML operation to work or what I need to re-factor?

Comment: @TonyWalsh Hard to know without looking at the code (feel free to open a new question if you need help) - I would recommend leaning hard on your unit tests, though. Try to reproduce the problem in a test and that can get you to the issue.